# Can the environmental keys that Parse Server is Using be verified inside the client app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I was wondering if/how can the Parse-Server environmental variables be verified inside a client IOS App.

For those of us that are yet uncomfortable with backend systems, it would be useful to be able to validate via the client side during testing that the backend Parse-Server is actually using the correct Environmental Keys.

Comment: Are you sure you want to continue using Parse? It's going offline next year.

Comment: No.  I will abandon Parse shortly.  Just wanted to solve this problem so that I can continue to use my original migrated database at mLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing the keys to setup parse-server such as appId, clientKey, masterKey, you can implement a verify cloud code.

Once you use appId (or you have set clientKey), you can call this function. Otherwise, you will get errors. You cannot use MasterKey in client-sdk. If you still want to test it, you can implement a rest api with masterKey on your client. But masterKey should not appear in client side, you should avoid user trigger this, or someone may get your masterKey.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("verify", function(request, response) {
    if(request.master==true){
        response.success(true);
    }else{
        response.error(new Error('MasterKey not matched'));
    }
});
```

**Edited**

By implement a globalConfig obj, verify it as you wish.

Here is a sample.

globalConfig.js

```
var globalConfig = {};

globalConfig.verify = function(key) {
    return globalConfig.keys.testKey==key;
}

module.exports = globalConfig;
```

index.js  (partial)

```
var globalConfig = require('./globalConfig.js');
var initObj = {
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  testKey: "this is test"
}
var api = new ParseServer(initObj);
globalConfig.keys = initObj;
```

and then you can use globalConfig.verify() to check your keys

a cloud code example

```
var globalConfig = require('../globalConfig.js');
Parse.Cloud.define('verify', function(req, res) {
  res.success(globalConfig.verify(req.params.testKey));
});
```

or you can use express post

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    //verify and response
})
```

Comment: I want to check the value of fileKey, as I am having trouble with the querying collections that have PFFile types.  They fail with Internal Server Error.  So want to rule out the fileKey as I think I am setting correctly.  The method that you have proposed seems interesting.   However, not sure how to implement.  Seems i need to know what object in parse-server holds the environment keys, at least.

Comment: How you setup parse-server, similar with parse-server-example?

Comment: Yes.  I initially used the deploy to AWS button on one of the how-to pages.  Then I cloned the parse-server-example, edited index.js and package.json.  Then I uploaded the new zip and deployed it to the parse-server-example instance.

Comment: You answered the question elegantly.  I am reaching for something else, as I am trying to understand why my Parse-Server implementation fails on PFFiles. But, for the question posed, this solution to capture the environment variables in another variable provides a good answer. Thank you.